# What is Calendar Activity for HTC / Motorola devices?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, calendar

I have developed widget with shortcut to Calendar Application.

I figured out this for Samsung device

- Package : com.android.calendar
- Class : com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity

And what about HTC and Motorola Calendar?
Anyone could share?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of package names and class names that I am using for a similar App.
Although I don't like the way I have to hard code it all. I would like to have a workaround that does not depend on the package name or class name, so that I don't have to send an update for my app, everytime some manufacturer changes one of the values.

For now, here you go :

```
{ "HTC Calendar", "com.htc.calendar",
"com.htc.calendar.LaunchActivity" },

{ "Standar Calendar", "com.android.calendar",
"com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity" },

{ "Froyo Nexus Calendar", "com.google.android.calendar",
"com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity" },

{ "Moto Blur Calendar", "com.motorola.blur.calendar",
"com.motorola.blur.calendar.LaunchActivity" },

{ "Samsung Galaxy S", "com.android.calendar",
"com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity" }
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Hope you can add more over time

Answer (score 0):

> I have developed widget with shortcut to Calendar Application

What "Calendar Application"? There are probably a dozen or two just in terms of what ship on devices, and there are undoubtedly hundreds of others out on the Play Store.

> I figured out this for Samsung device

No, you "figured out this for" **a** "Samsung device". Samsung makes more than one Android phone, and there is no guarantee that any given Samsung phone will necessarily use the same package and/or class name for their bundled calendar application.

> And what about HTC and Motorola Calendar?

They too make more than one Android phone, and there is no guarantee that any given phone from any manufacturer will necessarily use the same package and/or class name for their bundled calendar application.

And, of course, the package and/or class names could change with any firmware update.

And, of course, the user may not wish to use the bundled calendar application, but rather some other calendar application that they got from the Play Store or elsewhere.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. Yes your point is correct too. So what do you think the best solution? Let the users set their own shortcut? But at least for the first step default shortcut to stock Calendar app would be good enough.

Comment: @Halim: "So what do you think the best solution?" -- to be honest, I would recommend that you write some other app, since what you are trying to do is already handled by the operating system. "But at least for the first step default shortcut to stock Calendar app would be good enough" -- except that there is no single "stock Calendar app", as I have pointed out.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, we seems have misunderstanding. Actually I have developed a clock widget. And I want to let users get into stock Calendar app when users click on the widget. Therefore I need list of Calendar apps for variety of Android devices. Currently I have managed Calendar shorcut for majority Samsung devices. But I have no idea what is the package and class name for HTC and Motorola.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare I got your point. However for current time, basically I need a Calendar package and class name for HTC and Motorola devices. That's all. To make it more specific let's say for HTC Desire and for Motorola Droid Razr. Hope someone could share.